# Compiling c++, Makefile basics: variables, including libraries

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors

I'm struggling to understand how to compile a small linux app, uvccapture. [Its source is here](http://staticwave.ca/source/uvccapture/). My problems revolve around the Makefile, and satisfying the include requirements.

What I need to know is where I should be defining variables like `MATH_LIB`, (if at all), and what `-ljpeg` means, and what I need to do to satisfy them.

What have I tried? Reading tutorials and references about makefiles, and have tried compiling and changing options. The result: general confusion!!! I barely know what to ask. Perhaps someone could get me going.

I have put the source of jpeglib and uvccapture in the following directories:

```
~/src/jpeglib
~/src/uvccapture
```

So far, I am unable to get past the following error when I `cd` into `~/src/uvccapture` and run `make`:

```
jpeglib.h: No such file or directory
```

I'm compiling on a Raspberry Pi running the latest Raspbian 'Wheezy'.

The Makefile for UVCCapture is as follows:

```
CC=gcc
CPP=g++
APP_BINARY=uvccapture
VERSION = 0.4
PREFIX=/usr/local/bin

WARNINGS = -Wall

CFLAGS = -std=gnu99 -O2 -DLINUX -DVERSION=\"$(VERSION)\" $(WARNINGS)
CPPFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)

OBJECTS= uvccapture.o v4l2uvc.o

all:    uvccapture

clean:
    @echo "Cleaning up directory."
    rm -f *.a *.o $(APP_BINARY) core *~ log errlog

install:
    install $(APP_BINARY) $(PREFIX)

# Applications:
uvccapture: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC)   $(OBJECTS) $(XPM_LIB) $(MATH_LIB) -ljpeg -o $(APP_BINARY)
```

The source files only contains uvccapture.c and v412uvc.h. The top of uvccapture.c has the following include lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <jpeglib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <linux/videodev.h>

#include "v4l2uvc.h"
```

Any help overcoming the above error would be appreciated! And as a bonus, getting the whole thing to compile. Perhaps a simpler makefile can do? I don't know if I need to download MATH_LIB files, for example, or if they come with gcc.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually on a debian system all you'd need to do is: `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev`

Comment: Thanks that worked a treat! Next error is `linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory`. I ran `sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev` but the error persisted, and if I try to install libv4l2-dev it says it can't find such a package

Comment: When you need some infos you would get more results searching in the gcc documentation (-l is a gcc flag) than searching in the makefile documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-ljpeg` means to link with a library called libjpeg.a. Since you also don't have the header file  I would guess that you do not have this library installed on your system. The answer is to find that library and install it.